# How to better organize the declarations of these functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So as I understand it, you should always declare a function before it gets called.

However in the code below, how could this be restructured so that this philosophy is satisfied?

`fetchTags` is declared here as the 3rd function, somewhere below here I call it from a loadTags function.

After the tags are loaded, I then attached the EventListener and attach the 2nd function `scrollingTags`.

Once `scrollingTags` hits bottom and calls `loadMoreItems` which returns `checkScrollLimit` and if this `!LIMIT_REACHED` is true, limit is not reached, it calls `fetchTags` again which is declared below `checkScrollLimit`.

My code works so maybe this is a non-issue, just curious how other developers would treat this.

```
const checkScrollLimit = () => {
    if (!LIMIT_REACHED) {
        const infiniteScroll = true;
        PARAMS.start += this.limit;
        maxlimitCheck() ? LIMIT_REACHED = true : fetchTags(infiniteScroll);
    }
};

const scrollingTags = () => {
    const reachedBottom = () => tagsCol.scrollHeight - tagsCol.scrollTop === tagsCol.offsetHeight;
    const loadMoreItems = () => checkScrollLimit();
    if (reachedBottom()) loadMoreItems();
};

const fetchTags = (infiniteScroll) => {
    LIMIT_REACHED = false;
    return GetTagsFactory.getTags(false, Util.encodeTicker(this.ticker), PARAMS).then((tags) => {
        TOTAL_TAGS = tags.total;
        this.tags = fillTagsList(tags, infiniteScroll);
        tagsCol.addEventListener('scroll', scrollingTags);
        return this.tags;
    });
};
```

Comment: "you should always declare a function before it gets called." says who?

Comment: Try to write pure functions instead of dirty ones, they are more testable and readable. https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976#.xe41e3ne6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure's ok. The functions are all tightly coupled, which may make changes more of a hassle, but it's nothing super terrible.

It could be cleaner if you separated concerns a bit more. E.g. `fetchTags` would do *only* that: Fetch tags, but *not* append them to the page or anything. And `checkScrollLimit` would do *only* that, and just return a boolean instead of calling other functions.

Having `fetchTags` also append stuff to the page is what leads to attaching the event listener, which causes the circular dependency with `scrollingTags`, which in turn is coupled to `checkScrollLimit` which is coupled to `fetch....` - you get the idea.

So you could add higher-order functions - say, something like an `appendTags` function which calls `fetchTags` and `fillTagsList` and finally adds the event listener. Then `fetchTags` wouldn't be coupled to `scrollingTags` and vice versa; a higher-order function(s) would in charge to tying all the ends together.

Still, I'd say it's mostly a non-issue in this particular case. All your functions are *defined* before they're called, and that's what matters. The JS runtime doesn't care about the order of the function definitions, only that they have been defined before something tries to call them. So, really, you could mix them up however you want.

Sidenote: The `scrollingTags` function seems a little too complicated, though, what with wrapping `checkScrollLimit` in another local function. Could just skip that and call it directly.

---

On a related note, just your edification: If you had used "proper" function declarations - i.e. `function foo() {...}` – JavaScript would "hoist" those declarations and interpret them before starting the rest of the script evaluation. So in that case, the code would work even if you actually *called* a function before it had (seemingly) been defined. So, curiously, this works:

```
foo();

function foo() { ... } // hoisted; evaluated before anything else
```

but this doesn't:

```
foo(); // error: foo isn't defined (yet)

var foo = function () { ... } // not hoisted
```

and nor do the ES6 `=>` declarations.

Comment: Thanks so much man! I updated my code, posted a gist here :) I broke out the attachment of tags from gettingTags, and removed the pointless loadMoreItems function: https://gist.github.com/leongaban/bcde2ac54c9f4ee1fdab2215498d576a